# Lodash findKey() method

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

As a part of a challenge I need to implement the .findKey() method myself. Below is the solution proposition, however, I get an error "predicate is not a function".

```
const _ = {
  findKey(object, predicate) {
    for (let key in object) {
      let value = object[key];
      let predicateReturnValue = predicate(value);
      if (predicateReturnValue) {
        return key;
      };
    };
    undefined
    return undefined;
  }
};
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please have a look at this https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/findkey-recreating-lodash-library/376391/3

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findKey(object, predicate) {
    for (let key in object) {
        let value = object[key];
        let predicateReturnValue = predicate(value); 
        if (predicateReturnValue) {                   // just take the value
            return key;                               // return key
        }
    }
}


   const isEqual = a => b => a === b
    const object = { a: 'Apple', b: 'Beer', c: 'Cake' }
    
alert(findKey(object, isEqual('Apple')));
alert(findKey(object, isEqual('Cakes')));
```

Comment: By the way where are you trying it? Just copy paste it in console window of chrome you must get alerts.